# Using for_each with tolower()

Tags: c++, stl, foreach, g++, stl-algorithm

I am trying to use the STL function for_each to convert a string into lower case and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Here's the for_each line in question:

`clean = for_each(temp.begin(), temp.end(), low);`

Where temp is a string that is holding a string. And here's the function that I wrote for low:

```
void low(char& x)
{
x = tolower(x);
}
```

And the compiler error that I keep getting is as such:

```
error: invalid conversion from void (*)(char&) to char [-fpermissive]
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Here is the whole function that I am writing:

```
void clean_entry (const string& orig, string& clean)
{
string temp;
int beginit, endit;

beginit = find_if(orig.begin(), orig.end(), alnum) - orig.begin();
endit = find_if(orig.begin()+beginit, orig.end(), notalnum) - orig.begin();

temp = orig.substr(beginit, endit - beginit);

clean = for_each(temp.begin(), temp.end(), low);
}
```

Comment: I tried a test program and didn't get an error.  Can you provide a small complete example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for_each`'s return-value is the function that you passed it — in this case, `low`. So this:

```
clean = for_each(temp.begin(), temp.end(), low);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
for_each(temp.begin(), temp.end(), low);
clean = low;
```

when what you really want is probably this:

```
for_each(temp.begin(), temp.end(), low); // note: modifies temp
clean = temp;
```

(or you can just eliminate `temp` to begin with, and use `clean` throughout).

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what I was thinking. I guess I misinterpreted the way that for_each works.

Answer (score 7):

The standard idiom for what you are trying to do is

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string> 

std::string data = "Abc"; 
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), ::tolower);
```